# Why my app opens wrong folder in filemanager dialog?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app I have made smth like file manager. It is based on custom dialog which has recyclerview with custom adapter. I send files list and then open folder/file.

I have two problems:

1. I send all folders and also folders which names start from `.` like `.archivetemp`. I don't know how to send only ordinary names without dot based. Here I send data to adapter:

   ```
   fileList.clear()
   fileList.addAll(root.list())
   fileList.sort()

   val files = root.listFiles()
   Arrays.sort(files) { f1, f2 ->
       if (f1.isDirectory && !f2.isDirectory) {
           -1
       } else if (!f1.isDirectory && f2.isDirectory) {
           1
       } else {
           f1.compareTo(f2)
       }
   }

   fileManagerAdapter = FileManagerA(this, fileList, files)
   fileManagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
   fileManager.adapter = fileManagerAdapter
   ```

at emulator I receive ordinary list without dot based folders.

2. Second problem - when I click an item on my phone I open the wrong folder. For example folder is placed on 10 position but I open folder which is placed on 12 position. I think that this problem is caused by sending wrong folders list but I can be wrong.

So, how I can solve this problem and where I did the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list directory without `.` or `hidden` directory like:

**For Java**

```
//if the number of files is greater than 0, add the files and their names
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if(!files[i].isHidden()) 
       fileList.add(files[i].getName()); // Add non hidden files
}
```

**For Kotlin**

```
for (i in 0 until files.size) {
   if (!files[i].isHidden)
       fileList.add(files[i].name) // Add non hidden files
}
```

Comment: Your second problem with your position

Comment: If you get list without `hidden` directory then your second problem is solve automatically **(May be!!)**

Comment: one question - what is files variable? how I can get it?

Comment: you can get like `val files = root.listFiles()`

Comment: Now check it with new solution

Comment: I saw you edited answer, but I still have problem :( :( so, I send correct data to adapter, but when I click on item I move to wrong directory which starts from dot, but it also invisible :(

Comment: You can still getting `hidden` file in your list?

Comment: Have you check `if (!files[i].isHidden)` is working or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194033/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-dinesh-shingadiya).